# Continue from given folder when walking recursively through folder

Tags: python, os.walk

I'm walking recursively through a folder using json files that contain metadata to tag some ebook files and creating a `.ts` folder with other json files. The process has stopped with an error and I don't want to start from zero. Is there any way given the last processed folder to continue from there? By continue I mean to not do any processing until that folder is visited.

```
def process_files_not_in_hidden_folder(path: str, extension: str) -> None:
    """
    Get all files recursively from parent folder,
    except for the ones that are in hidden folders
    """
    for root, subdirs, filenames in os.walk(path):
        subdirs[:] = [d for d in subdirs if not d[0] == '.']
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith(extension):
                meta_file = os.path.join(root, filename)
                export_tags(meta_file)
```

Comment: can you add the error here?

Comment: you can add some variable `process = False` and use it to skip functions. and use some `if` which compare folders with your folder and set `process = True`

Comment: maybe you should add `try/except` to catch errors and to continue code with next file/folder.

Comment: if your code create some files then you could skip code if file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't tested.

You can use variable with start folder and run code only if it `None`.

And when it is not `None` then compare with `root` and set it `None` when they are the same.

Something like this.

```
def process_files_not_in_hidden_folder(path: str, extension: str, start_folder=None) -> None:
    """
    Get all files recursively from parent folder,
    except for the ones that are in hidden folders
    """
        
    for root, subdirs, filenames in os.walk(path):
        
        # search `start_folder` (if not `None`)
        if start_folder and start_folder == root:
           start_folder = None
                
        # skip if it didn't find `start_folder`
        if not start_folder:  # it can't be `else`
            subdirs[:] = [d for d in subdirs if not d[0] == '.']
            for filename in filenames:
                if filename.endswith(extension):
                    meta_file = os.path.join(root, filename)
                    export_tags(meta_file)
```

---

**BTW:**

If your files can make problem then you could add code in `try/except` to catch error and continue code with next folder.

And if your code creates some file for every folder then you could skip folder if file already exists.